# Getting incorrect POS tagging

Tags: nlp, spacy, linguistics

I am trying to get the POS for the sentence 
`dragon flies to rescue the princess` using below code

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
doc = nlp("dragon flies to rescue the princess")

for token in doc:
    print(f'{token.text:{12}} {token.pos_:{12}}')
```

Output for above code:

```
dragon       NOUN         
flies        NOUN         
to           PART         
rescue       VERB         
the          DET          
princess     NOUN
```

Here, 'flies' is considered as NOUN while it is VERB, is it because spacy is considering 'dragon flies' as a single word?

what should I do , if I wish to get "VERB" as POS for flies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running your example, there are two things to note:

1. Spacy models are statistically trained models, that individually have a specific [POS accuracy](https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_md), in this case around 97%. Therefore, *some* mistakes are always to be expected, specifically when you're dealing with a corpus of a wide variety of sentences.
2. Spacy can of course only provide meaningful tags if the sentence is grammatically correct, which is not the case for your above example.

When I run the corrected sentence "A dragon flies to rescue the princess.", the output is

```
The          DET         
dragon       NOUN        
flies        VERB        
to           PART        
rescue       VERB        
the          DET         
princess     NOUN        
.            PUNCT
```

and therefore exactly what we expected. Should your dataset contain sentences that are dealing with such syntactic errors, the "easiest" solution would probably to hand-annotate some of the examples, and utilize Spacy's training functionality, details for this can be found [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training). Even then, it is not guaranteed that you get significantly better results unless you annotate a lot of data, and can assert that most of the samples have "similar-looking" errors.